# Bicycle parking at Narita airport

Tags: airports, bicycles, tokyo, nrt

Where can I park my bicycle at Narita airport for a week?

Of course a safe and legal parking space would be the best, but if there are none are there tolerated places where people usually leave their bicycles.

If everywhere in Narita Airport is strictly forbidden, is there a place nearby where I can quickly go and drop my bicycle before coming back to board the plane? *(let's say the bicycle was refused as luggage by the airline)*

Comment: Here's a video of someone riding around trying to find a place to put his bicycle; and just finding a random area next to the car garage where a few others had given up.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTIZCz-sjpk  Not something you'd want to do for more than an hour or so, though.

Answer (score 6):

Have never seen public bicycle parking at Narita, there maybe something for employees (though based on traffic on the roads leading to Narita, I am guessing employees go by train or bus).

The Narita Airport Hostel mentions bicycle parking, so perhaps something could be arranged through them, especially if you overnight before or after.

There is a baggage storage service available in both terminal 1 and 2 where you maybe able to leave your bike in its packing box, if the airline won't let you check in on the flight.

Or perhaps arrange to leave it wherever you are staying beforehand in Tokyo, then simply take the train to/from the airport for your week abroad.